# Tracking capable metal detector

Tags: inductive

I am starting a project up at the moment, where i need to develop a metal detector for tracking purposes. In other words, i need the ability of knowing exactly which direction the metal is being dragged with basis from the metal detector.

[image]

Basically the image above explains my "idea", if its feasible or stupid is something else.
It should be possible to drag the metal in any direction (360 degrees).

Is there a different approach to detecting the absolute direction of where the metal is being dragged towards or does this seem possible?

EDIT: Omni-directional metal detection

Comment: a lot of R&D on mine detectors with high sensitivity and direction finding.  Preferred sensors use ground penetrating radar for eliminating surface soil iron content and ground clutter as well as non-metallic types burried.

Comment: The purpose is not soil or anything at all. Its free air detecting, the metal will be holded by a human hand, dragging it around.

Comment: So you need a 3 D sensor not a 2D sensor.. ie. omnidirectional.  High sensitivity Metal detectors use differential loops. in this case they need to be aimed apart with differential sensitivity for a left right direction seeking and null adjustment for offsets. Same for up/down.. using non-harmonically tuned alternate frequency.

Comment: @Richman, you are actually mentioning something that i might have forgotten all about in the thinking process. I indeed need a 3D sensor, as it requires ability of moving in- and outwards aswell. But does the 4 coil design seem feasible and realistic in this case?

Comment: Not recommended for the uninitiated .. Try this https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.maxcom.magdetector&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLm1heGNvbS5tYWdkZXRlY3RvciJd

Comment: @Richman, do you have any sources on omnidirectional metal detection or the techniques at least?

Comment: No. . Search 3d magnitometer

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately only links me to finished compasses and magnetometers..

Comment: @Richman, if we only speak in 2D, would the 4 coil method be feasible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider this method: -
[image]

Coil A, B, C and D are 4 receiving coils and the larger outer coil is a transmit coil. The magnetic field disturbance caused by the metal will (if ferrous in nature) increase the flux coupling to the receive coil that the metal is located nearest to. If the metal is non-ferrous, the transmit coil will induce eddy-currents in the metal and the receive coil it is nearest to will therefore have a decreased flux coupling.

Increases or decreases in flux coupling will result in increases or decreases in the signal voltage on the relevant receive coils. All coils need to be ideally tuned to resonance with parallel caps but this is only necessary if the metal item is small. The transmit coil would ideally be parallel tuned for maximum efficiency of producing flux.

If the pieces of metal are small you will probably need to tune the rx coils to resonance. I'd look at an operating frequency of sub 50kHz and probably somewhere more like 10kHz as even large chunks of iron will still produce a net ferromagnetic effect despite the metal being conductive and also producing eddy-current (anti ferrous effects). As frequency gets towrds about 100kHz large-ish pieces of ferrous (circa 6mm and above) will start to look more "conductive" than ferromagnetic.

The circuitry is all fairly straight-forward. An analogue oscillator and 4 amplifiers but the trick is mapping the coil outputs against actual position of the metal. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've done much research on actually detecting metal but [here](http://www.micro-examples.com/articles/index.php/PicoDetector) is a simple metal detector with a low parts count. Maybe you could replicate it multiple times and take the output of each to a "master" controller.

Comment: Hi Brandon, i have tested simple metal detectors. But i cannot figure out a robust design for this purpose. I need a pure analog design, no µC or such.

Comment: I see... that does complicate it a bit. I will do some more research and if I find anything useful to add will do so asap.

Comment: In this day and age, I'd be very tempted to go digital as early in the chain as possible, since digital implementations are cheap and free of component value variation/drift.  It's also a lot easier to throw in complicated processing, and experiment with it.